# Installed @element-plus/icons-vue through npm, but WebStorm still prompts me that I cannot parse the file 'icons-vue'

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I installed `@element-plus/icons-vue` through npm, and I can find it in the node_modules. This is my usage:

```
import {User, Loading} from "@element-plus/icons-vue"
```

But WebStorm still prompts me that I cannot parse the file `icons-vue` and use a red line under `icons-vue`.

[err image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eDFC.png)
How can I solve this?

Comment: what error cn you see namely? Please share screenshots

Comment: I added the picture of error reporting. Can you see it？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebStorm team replied to me, change "types" in `node_modules/@element-plus/icons-vue/package.json` from `"types": "index.d.ts"` to `"types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts"`,it works